# How many variables can be used in a single sub/function of vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have built a simple function but it needs around 11-12 variable that have the same integer type. Every time I tried to used with more than 10 variables, the first one often gets wrong while the others are correctly calculated. If I reduce the number of variables down to 10, they they are all correct.
Does it mean hat vba can only store 10 variables with the same type at a time? Or it is my computer' limit :))

This is my code, btb return the wrong value while the others is correct, but if I delete variable "a" and all the code related to it, then btb return correctly

```
Sub regionCount()
Dim btb, dbb, hn, ntb, dnb, tnbBS, tnbNS, hcm1, hcm2, hcm3, a As Integer

btb = dbb = hn = dnb = tnbBS = tnbNS = hcm1 = hcm2 = hcm3 = a = 0

For Each mycell In Worksheets(1).Range("E2:E382")
    If mycell.Value = "Khu vuc Bac Trung Bo" Then
        btb = btb + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "Khu vuc Dong Bac Bo" Then
        dbb = dbb + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "Khu vuc Ha Noi" Then
        hn = hn + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "Khu vuc Nam Trung Bo" Then
        ntb = ntb + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "Khu vuc Dong Nam Bo" Then
        dnb = dnb + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "Khu vuc Tay Nam Bo  - Bac song hau" Then
        tnbBS = tnbBS + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "Khu vuc Tay Nam Bo  - Nam song hau" Then
        tnbNS = tnbNS + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "Khu vuc TPHCM_1" Then
        hcm1 = hcm1 + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "Khu vuc TPHCM_2" Then
        hcm2 = hcm2 + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "Khu vuc TPHCM_3" Then
        hcm3 = hcm3 + 1
    ElseIf mycell.Value = "-- None --" Then
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next mycell

Range("C5").Value = btb
Range("d5").Value = dbb
Range("e5").Value = hn
Range("f5").Value = ntb
Range("g5").Value = dnb
Range("h5").Value = tnbBS
Range("i5").Value = tnbNS
Range("j5").Value = hcm1
Range("k5").Value = hcm2
Range("l5").Value = hcm3
Range("m5").Value = a
```

End Sub

Comment: Sounds like operator error to me.

Comment: Oh, you have the same problem?

Comment: Operator error? Yes, but only on rare occasions.

Comment: May be to use array? Or `ParamArray`?

Comment: I have tried a few time, and it return the first value wrong all the time. It is really annoying. Step down to 10 variables and the first one will return correctly

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: There is no inherent problem with using 10 (or even 100) variables, as long as you use them *correctly*.   You don't show any code, so it's impossible to know what your problem might be.

Comment: I'll second @TimWilliams. I've used more than 10 variables of the same type on some basic algorithms and it works fine. What's important is you have the correct logic. Post your code and how you used them so we can help you.

Comment: This takes me back to the days of programming a HP71B - variable names could be single characters such as `A`, `B`, `C`, etc or a character and a digit such as `A0`, `A1`, etc, so a maximum of 286 possible variables.  Single character variiables consumed 1 byte of memory for each time they were used in the code, and character/digit variables consumed 1.5 bytes per use.  So to save precious memory space (4Kb total) we had to use the single character names for the most frequently used variables.  Ahh, the good old days.

Comment: I've added my code, please take a look, thanks you guys alot!

Comment: VBs don't store the variable name, they store the memory address - 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @ACatInLove If your last comment was a reference to my HP71B days (with different storage requirements based on variable names) then you should remember that the source code, including variable names, has to be stored somewhere or else you would never be able to edit the code at a future date. The HP71B optimised it (slightly) by tokenising the source code instead of storing it as straight text.  So `A0` could be stored in just 12 bits instead of 16 bits even though it is two characters. And when you edited it, it detokenised it.

Comment: My first computer has 2000 bytes of RAM and also tokenised commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement

```
btb = dbb = hn = dnb = tnbBS = tnbNS = hcm1 = hcm2 = hcm3 = a = 0
```

should be

```
btb = 0
dbb = 0
hn = 0
dnb = 0
tnbBS = 0
tnbNS = 0
hcm1 = 0
hcm2 = 0
hcm3 = 0
a = 0
```

---

Consider the statement

```
a = b = c
```

That is interpreted as

```
a = (b = c)
```

where `(b = c)` is a logical expression.  So, if `b` is the same value as `c` (which it will be if the variables have all been left to the default initialisation of `0`) then `a` will be set to `True` (i.e. `-1`)

The way you had your statement laid out would have set the value on the very left to be -1 (if you had an odd number of variables in the line) or to 0 (if you had an even number).

---

It should also be noted that

```
Dim btb, dbb, hn, ntb, dnb, tnbBS, tnbNS, hcm1, hcm2, hcm3, a As Integer
```

is equivalent to

```
Dim btb As Variant, dbb As Variant, hn As Variant, ntb As Variant, dnb As Variant, _
    tnbBS As Variant, tnbNS As Variant, hcm1 As Variant, hcm2 As Variant, _
    hcm3 As Variant, a As Integer
```

It is not the same as

```
Dim btb As Integer, dbb As Integer, hn As Integer, ntb As Integer, dnb As Integer, _
    tnbBS As Integer, tnbNS As Integer, hcm1 As Integer, hcm2 As Integer, _
    hcm3 As Integer, a As Integer
```

Comment: So, it can't be stacked  like that. How stupid I am :)). Thank you all

Comment: @MinhHa - I have edited the answer to also include an explanation of what your code was doing.

Comment: Wow, how dangerous it is. I didn't know that they mean totally different when we stack up like that. One more question, when declaring the variables, should I keep the way I am doing or split them up?

Comment: I prefer splitting them up because they make it easier to find the individual declarations, but it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @MinhHa As jkpieterse says, it is **personal preference**.  My personal preference is one per line, with the `As` part tabbed out to character 33 on the line (which usually leaves me enough room for some longish variable names) so that the `As type` parts all line up neatly.  But that's just me liking things to look neat.

Answer (score 3):

> A single project can contain up to 32,000 "identifiers" (any
>   nonreserved keyword), which include, but are not limited to, forms,
>   controls, modules, variables, constants, procedures, functions, and
>   objects. Note that the actual number of identifiers is limited to
>   available memory.
>
> Variable names in Visual Basic can be no longer than 255 characters,
>   and the names of forms, controls, modules, and classes cannot be
>   longer than 40 characters. Visual Basic imposes no limit on the actual
>   number of distinct objects in a project.
>
> Code Limitations
>
> The amount of code that can be loaded into a form, class, or standard
>   module is limited to 65,534 lines. A single line of code can consist
>   of up to 1023 bytes. Up to 256 blank spaces can precede the actual
>   text on a single line, and no more than twenty-four line-continuation
>   characters ( _) can be included in a single logical line.
>
> Procedures, Types, and Variables There is no limit on the number of
>   procedures per module. Each procedure can contain up to 64K of code.
>   If a procedure or module exceeds this limit, Visual Basic generates a
>   compile-time error. If you encounter this error, you can avoid it by
>   breaking extremely large procedures into several smaller procedures,
>   or by moving module-level declarations into another module.
>
> Visual Basic uses tables to store the names of identifiers (variables,
>   procedures, constants, and so on) in your code. Each table is limited
>   to 64K.
>
> DLL Declare Table Each form and code module uses a table that contains
>   a structure describing a DLL entry point. Each structure uses
>   approximately 40 bytes, with a total restricted size of 64K, resulting
>   in roughly 1,500 declarations allowed per module.
>
> Project-Name Table The entire application uses a single table that
>   contains all names. These include:
>
> Constant names
>
> Variable names
>
> User-defined — type definition names
>
> Module names
>
> DLL-procedure declaration names  The project name table is unlimited
>   in total size, but is limited to a total of 32K case-sensitive unique
>   entries. If the limit is reached, reuse private identifiers in
>   different modules to limit the number of unique entries to 32K.
>
> Import Table Every reference to an identifier in a different module
>   creates an entry in the Import Table. Each such entry is a minimum of
>   24 bytes and is restricted to 64K, resulting in roughly 2,000
>   references per module.
>
> Module-Entries Table This table accepts up to 125 bytes per module,
>   with a total limit of 64K, resulting in about 400 modules per project.
>
> The following limitations apply to variables in the Visual Basic
>   language.
>
> Form, Standard, and Class Module Data The data segment (that is, the
>   data defined in the Declarations section) of the VBA module of any
>   form or module in Visual Basic can be up to 64K. This data segment
>   contains the following data:
>
> Local variables declared with Static.
>
> Module-level variables other than arrays and variable-length strings.
>
> 4 bytes for each module-level array and variable-length string. 
>   Procedures, Types, and Variables If a procedure or module exceeds the
>   64K code limit, Visual Basic generates a compile-time error.
>
> If you define a procedure that has more than 64K of local variables
>   defined, you get the error "Too many local nonstatic variables."
>
> If you define a module that has more than 64K of module-level
>   variables defined, or if you define a User-Defined Type larger than
>   64K, you get the error "Fixed or static data can't be larger than
>   64K."
>
> If you encounter this error, you can avoid it by breaking extremely
>   large procedures into several smaller procedures, or by moving
>   module-level declarations into another module.
>
> An array declared as a variable doesn't contribute to the entire size
>   of the array; only the array descriptor counts toward the 64K limit.
>   So it is acceptable, for example, to have a declaration such as Dim
>   x(1000000) As Byte either in a procedure or at module level. Out of
>   memory problems occur, however, if you declare a large, fixed-size
>   array in a record, then declare instances of those records as
>   variables.
>
> User-Defined Types No variable of a user-defined type can exceed 64K,
>   although the sum of variable-length strings in a user-defined type may
>   exceed 64K (variable-length strings occupy only 4 bytes each in the
>   user-defined type; the actual contents of a string are stored
>   separately). User-defined types can be defined in terms of other
>   user-defined types, but the total size of the types cannot exceed 64K.
>
> Stack Space Arguments and local variables in procedures take up stack
>   space at run time. Module-level and static variables do not take up
>   stack space because they are allocated in the data segment for forms
>   or modules. Any DLL procedures you call use this stack while they are
>   executing.
>
> Visual Basic itself uses some of the stack for its own purposes, such
>   as storing intermediate values when evaluating expressions.
>
> Total available stack size for Visual Basic is one megabyte (1MB) per
>   thread. A stack may grow beyond this, however, if there is adjacent
>   free memory.
>
> For More Information   For tips on conserving stack space, see
>   "Designing for Performance and Compatibility."

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716295(v=vs.60).aspx‎ and nearby pages.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two things wrong with your code:

1. Declaration is incorrect

   ```
   Dim btb, dbb, hn, ntb, dnb, tnbBS, tnbNS, hcm1, hcm2, hcm3, a As Integer
   ```

   Multiple declarations on a single line are allowed, but each variable needs its own `As` part. Currently, only `a` is declared as `Integer`, the others will be `Variant`. Change to:

   ```
   Dim btb As Integer, dbb As Integer, hn As Integer, ntb As Integer, dnb As Integer, tnbBS As Integer, tnbNS As Integer, hcm1 As Integer, hcm2 As Integer, hcm3 As Integer, a As Integer
   ```
2. Multiple assignments on a single line are not allowed, only the first one is performed. So in this case:

   ```
   btb = dbb = hn = dnb = tnbBS = tnbNS = hcm1 = hcm2 = hcm3 = a = 0
   ```

   only the value of `btb` is changed to `False` as

   ```
   dbb = hn = dnb = tnbBS = tnbNS = hcm1 = hcm2 = hcm3 = a = 0
   ```

   evaluates to `False`.

Comment: I didn't even notice that, @YowE3K have already pointed it out. Thank you alot

Comment: I now see that, his answers was probably posted while I was editing mine :-)

Comment: I would love to give you a tick, but I can give only one, haha. Thank you all

Comment: "Multiple assignments on a single line are not allowed".  FWIW, although I didn't mention it in my own answer (simply because I didn't think about it at the time) multiple assignments on a single **line** are allowed.  They just can't be done in a single **statement**.  E.g. the single line `btb = 0 : dbb = 0 : hn = 0 : dnb = 0 : tnbBS = 0 : tnbNS = 0 : hcm1 = 0 : hcm2 = 0 : hcm3 = 0 : a = 0` is valid.  (But my personal preference is not to use it.)

Comment: You're right. I never do multiple statements on a single line, which is why that doesn't apply to mme :-)